# Cannot access CSS from JS in Rails app

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I've got a Rails app that uses WYSIHTML in parts. It's controlled like so:

```
// richtext
if($('.richtext').length) {
  var editor = new wysihtml5.Editor(document.querySelector('.richtext'), {
    toolbar: 'wysihtml5-toolbar',
    parserRules:  wysihtml5ParserRules,
    stylesheets: '/assets/wysihtml5-stylesheet.css'
  });
}
```

This works fine locally, but `wysihtml5-stylesheet.css` cannot be found remotely. I've tried messing with asset pipeline/precompilation without luck. Any thoughts? It seems to have happened recently, i.e., it was working before. No settings other than what I just mentioned have been changed.

Please help.

**Update**

Even with `asset_path` the file can't be found:

```
stylesheets: '<%= asset_path "wysihtml5-stylesheet.css" %>'
```

Comment: on production, assets are compiled and are given a hash at the end of the filename which is most probably the reason why you can't see it.  look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_path for the asset_path method

Comment: Same problem, just with the MD5 hash at the end, i.e., cannot find `http://domain.com/assets/wysihtml5-stylesheet-9d0d93a7a284f16a3dea08a722430b272064c192b7c57a41329d7f86a8adb7da.css `

Comment: hmm you can't actually set the md5 hash directly. you have to use the rails helpers to generate the link to the file or add the file directly under the public folder.

Comment: Yeah, I used `asset_path`. Still gets a 404.

Comment: hmm weird. can you try going directly to the url?

Comment: Yeah, nada there. It's definitely in the commit, and it works fine locally, like I say.

Comment: hmm it most probably have something to do with how your assets are served in production.   search around for `serve_static_files` option for rails 4 and tinker with it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was environment specific and nothing to do with Rails.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is almost certainly in how you're calling your `stylesheet`.

--

In production, Sprockets [fingerprints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark) the asset files - adding large md5 hashes to them - making it incorrect to reference them with their "static" names (it simply won't work).

The way around this is to use one of the `asset_path helpers` to call the file (it will reference the file either in its "static" form, or "fingerprinted" form).

You've done this already, BUT I think you'll need to [add `.erb` to your JS file](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#javascript-coffeescript-and-erb) to get it to work:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js.erb
if($('.richtext').length) {
  var editor = new wysihtml5.Editor(document.querySelector('.richtext'), {
    toolbar: 'wysihtml5-toolbar',
    parserRules:  wysihtml5ParserRules,
    stylesheets: "<%=j asset_path('wysihtml5-stylesheet.css') %>"
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but yeah, `.erb` was already added to the JS file.